# Change JavaScript NaN Message to Something Else

Tags: javascript

I've got an `input[type="text"]` that throws up a NaN error until another box is filled. I know why the message is appearing, that's not a problem, it's correct. I'm just wondering if I can change 'NaN' to something more descriptive for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(isNaN(input.value)) {
    input2.value = '';//or a message of your choice
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Test the value with isNaN(value) and if true then handle it however you want.